# time format on my sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

my c# program selects a datetime field from database and returns the data like the following:

```
21/06/2012 4:11:48 p.m.
```

it is not stored this way though (it's stored like 2012/06/21 15:19:10:000).
my locale is set to English/New Zealand

but when I try to save it back to database

the `ISDATE()` sql function doesn't like that format and just returns NULL. Do I have any options to set the time format in sql or c#? What in sql or c# is making it put "p.m."? (instead of just "PM", which by the way works)

**Summing up the problem**

[See latest related link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11144907/139698)

Comment: Can you show us what "when I try to save it back to database" means? e.g. show the actual code? SQL Server is likely expecting m/d/y not d/m/y. Why are you using unsafe and ambiguous datetime formats? You should be using `yyyymmdd` for the date portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be saving it in the database as text at all - you should be using the relevant data type such as `DATETIME`, and passing `DateTime` values from .NET to the database using SQL parameters. If you're using the right data type, the value won't actually be *stored* as "2012/06/21 15:19:10:000" at all. That may be how you see it in SQL Server Studio or something similar, but that doesn't mean it's the raw storage format.

Logically, a date/time doesn't have a format any more than the number ten is "10" (decimal) vs "A" (hex). Avoid string conversions as far as you can, and your life will be easier.

Comment: I can't stress enough how important it is to not "stringly type" any of your data if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Note: See Jon's response about properly saving the DateTime in the database rather than a string.

For C# String formatting:

The DateTime object can output in different formats using the .ToString() function.

Please see the following links

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)
- [DateTime.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx)

So, for example:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss");
```

That will output in the format you have in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is related to the Set language setting in sql.

Similar to this question: [SQL Server ISDATE() Function - Can someone explain this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331817/sql-server-isdate-function-can-someone-explain-this)

Can you try to set your sql language to match your format?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the SQL datetime formats should be recognizable by C# `DateTime.Parse(youSQLDatetimeVariable)`. I find it a bit odd what's happening in your case.

Like other said you really shouldn't but here is how you can convert DateTime to various formats:

```
SELECT Convert(VARCHAR, MyDateTimeField, 112) from MyTable
```

That number (112 ) indicates the DateTime format that will appear as Varchar
All formats can be found here in details:
http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Or within your C# code with

```
YourDatetimeVariable.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Or whatever format you want within those quotes where MM- month number, dd - day number, yyyy - year.