# isdate and new zealand returning false

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here the problem:

```
select ISDATE('2012-06-21 4:11 P.M.')
```

The culture is en-NZ (New Zealand) and the string date above is how they format their dates.

How do I make ISDATE true in this case?

Comment: `dd/MM/yyyy`, not `yyyy/MM/dd`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc4ky857(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why are there dots in `P.M.`? Can you explain how this string format was generated? Did someone type it in somewhere?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - My c# console thread culture is set to en-NZ and when I pull a date field from the database this is what the datetime value looks like when I inspect the DataTable.

Comment: Then you should apply proper formatting to the date, and convert it to an unambiguous string, before your wonky C# console gets ahold of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would control the string format better than that. You shouldn't care whether the culture is EN-NZ or anything else if you pass in a standard format, such as:

```
SELECT ISDATE('20120621 16:11'); -- will never fail regardless of locale/language/DMY
```

If you need to allow people to enter dates in any format they wish, then you have to deal with it in various ways. For example:

```
SELECT ISDATE(CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE('2012-06-21 4:11 P.M.', '.', ''), 120));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select ISDATE('21-06-2012 4:11 P.M.')
```

this link is a useful one in your case

http://jefferychinet.blogspot.com/2009/02/sql-server-2005-change-datetime-format.html

Comment: I couldn't get this to work using any format for the date, because of the `P.M.`. Did you try this? And why are you yelling again?