# SET DATEFORMAT back to what it was

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

So for one operation I need to perform I need to set the Dateformat to ymd to make sure all date strings are yyyy-mm-dd

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd
SET @valid = ISDATE(@DateString)
```

Now, I always want to put the server back the way I found it so is there anyway I can capture or know what the dateformat was before I changed it?

In testing I found this issue.  Now I can solve it by looking at string lengths, but I don't know why the third select statement is valid

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd
select ISDATE('2015-04-15') -- 1
select ISDATE('2015-14-05') -- 0
select ISDATE('05-04-2005') -- 1 ??
```

Comment: Unexpected behaviour is possibly related to SET LANGUAGE, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331817/sql-server-isdate-function-can-someone-explain-this) question.

Comment: Interesting even if I set the language to Swedish which has a default of ymd, the third is still valid? Maybe because the Server default install is the last override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid date in XML is yyyy-mm-dd so you can use the XML datatype in SQL Server and do "try cast" in there to see if the string value is a valid date or not.

```
declare @T table(D varchar(10))

insert into @T(D) values
('2015-04-15'),
('2015-14-05'),
('05-04-2005');

select cast('' as xml).exist('sql:column("T.D") cast as xs:date?') as IsDate
from @T as T
```

Result:

```
IsDate
------
1
0
0
```

**Why does '05-14-2005' return 1?**

SQL Server tries to be helpful here and finds the position of the year part by identifying 4 digits in a row and uses `set dateformat` to figure out the order by month and day.

**Now, I always want to put the server back the way I found it**

`set dateformat` is a setting for each connection so maby you don't actually have to restore it?

To get the current value for your connection you can use:

```
select date_format
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where session_id = @@spid
```

Answer (score 1):

### SQL Server 2008 and Below

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#yourTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #yourTable;

SELECT * INTO #yourTable
FROM (
    SELECT '2015-04-15' testDates UNION ALL SELECT '2015-14-05' UNION ALL SELECT '05-04-2015'
) A

SELECT  *,
        CASE
            WHEN    ISNUMERIC(LEFT(testDates,4)) = 1 --checks if first four char are a year
                    AND SUBSTRING(testDates,6,2) <= 12 --checks if middle two numbers are valid months
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
FROM #yourTable
```

### SQL Server 2012 and Above

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATE,'2015-04-15',102) --'2015-04-15'
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATE,'2015-14-05',102) --NULL
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATE,'05-04-2015',102) --NULL

--This would get your results from a table
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN TRY_CONVERT(DATE,yourCol,102) IS NOT NULL 
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
FROM yourTable
```